# custom paths added to tsConfig file aren't recognized in Angular8

Tags: angular, typescript

I added a custom path to my tsConfig file and figure out why Angular won't recognize it.  I noticed angular already has a `baseUrl` property which is set to `./` which I'm assuming starts from the current folder the tsConfig file is in. The code I added looks like thi

```
"paths": {
      "@interfaces/*": ["src/app/interfaces/*"]
    }
```

this is throwing a **TS2307** error when I try to import it into a component.  My entire ts.config file looks like this

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@interfaces/*": ["src/app/interfaces/*"]
    }
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

What do I need to do to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just launched VSCode and all of a sudden the error was gone.  I have the node terminal open running my `ng serve` and using the terminal inside VSCode to generate components.  Maybe something in there somehow updated itself.  Before I had closed and re-served my project so it could re-compile with the update but that alone didn't seem to work.  Hopefully this can point someone with more experience "under the hood" towards a bug if this essentially shouldn't be an issue.